# Altair - filter range by slider binding

Tags: python, vega-lite, altair

I am trying to achieve something similar to [this example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/us_population_pyramid_over_time.html), except instead of using the slider to select discrete values, I would like it to serve as the cutoff point in a `transform_filter` (i.e. values < slider value).

Right now I have something like this:

```
import altair as alt
from altair.expr import datum

slider = alt.binding_range(min=data.refill_time.min().value,
                           max=data.refill_time.max().value,
                           step = 1)
select_date = alt.selection_single(name='refill_time',
                                   fields=['refill_time'],
                                   bind=slider)

refills = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar(
).transform_filter(
    datum.refill_time < select_date.ref()
).encode(
    alt.X('refill_count:Q',
    alt.Y('group:N')
).add_selection(
    select_date
)

display(refills)
```

I tried looking at the data from `slider` but I couldn't find any fields that return it's current value (`.ref()` attempt). I also tried changing the `selection_single` to `_multi` and `_interval` but I just got invalid specification errors - I couldn't find any way to define the `binding_range` that would make sense to the selection.

Is this possible in altair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following filter expression:

```
transform_filter(
    "datum.refill_time < refill_time_refill_time"
)
```

where the strange looking "refill_time_refill_time" is build up by the selection name "refill_time" and the field name "refill_time". Although I am not 100% sure if thats correct, but in any case it should be the "slider text", so in the linked example it would be "year_year".

Comment: FWIW, I believe it's possible to do this without using the awkward looking `"refill_time_refill_time"`. What you would write instead is `transform_filter(select_date.refill_time)` (Note: there is no double-quotes!). Unfortunately the OP didn't provide the data so I can't test it using the original example, but I have something similar on my local dataset. This was inspired by: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2008#issuecomment-621428053